# How do I hide a whole cell in a grid with css when overflowing

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

I am trying to make a grid that takes up the whole viewport. It have square cells with an aspect-ratio of 1. The width of the squares scales up with the width of the screen which changes the height of the square. I would like to hide the overflowing cells on the bottom entirely when they have a part out of the screen. Currently the overflow propperty only hides the part of the cell that gets out of the viewport

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obEA7.png)

```html
<body>
  <div id="projects">
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
    <div><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
:root {
  --light-color: #e8e6e3;
  --grid-div-min-width: 200px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  background: #282c2d;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#projects {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;

  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  gap: .2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(var(--grid-div-min-width), 1fr));
  overflow: hidden;
}

#projects>div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

#projects>div>img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

I have tried adding "overflow hidden to the child-elements" but it seems to get rid of the aspect-ratio

[image illustrating the result of the sentence before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG8nF.jpg)

I tryed manually setting the amount of row like I did for the columns but the content of the cells did not fit inside the rows

[image illustrating the result of the sentence before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD1zt.png)

Comment: Please post the code (html and CSS) so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @web-tiki I added the code HTML to my question

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve a grid with square cells that takes up the whole viewport is to use `display: grid` and set the `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns` properties to `1fr`, which means that each row and column will take up an equal amount of space. You can also set the `grid-gap` property to add some space between the cells.

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cell {
  /* Add styles for the cells here */
}
```

Next,

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
  <div class="cell"><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
  <div class="cell"><img src="https://baptiste-crepin.fr/repo-bg/Placeholder.png"></div>
  <!-- Add more cells here -->
</div>
```

This will create a grid with cells that are square and take up the whole viewport, and any cells that overflow will be hidden.

Comment: It does not seem to work, 
the lines 
```html
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
```
are grayed out